# get the time difference between two times in format hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript

I have two times in `HH:mm:ss` format. I am trying to calculate the time difference between two times.
like

```
 var timeStart = '01:00:24';
   var timeEnd = '01:00:34'
  var timeDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
```

How can i perform this with a javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split them with `:` and take difference. And again join them with `:`

```js
    
var start = '01:00:24';
var end = '01:00:34';
var diff = start.split(':').map((item,index) => end.split(':')[index] - item).join(':')
console.log(diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can prepone to both a fixed date and do the subtraction:

```
var start = '01:00:24';
var end = '01:00:34';
start = '2017-11-8' + start;
end = '2017-11-8' + end;
var diff = +end - +start; // outputs 10000 (in ms)
```